# Is a 256 bit HMAC-SHA256 key compromised if the tail is used for identification?

Tags: keys, hmac, sha-256

Using a truncated hash of a key seems to be a safe way to identify the key (i.e. key fingerprint), but what about truncating a key itself in the case of HMAC-SHA256?

Example:

```
$ key=`openssl rand 32 -base64`
    $ keyId=`echo $key | cut -c 40-43`
$ echo $key
RlBDpvx3pCD/rs2SyeHX0enLOxCP7mEQCB8zvtQhD6g=
$ echo $keyId
hD6g
$
```

Is using `$keyId` as a way to identify the key secure?  I recognize that the security strength will be reduced, but is it a negligible/acceptable amount?  Is there something in the literature that addresses how disclosing the tail of a HMAC key impacts security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't seriously impact the security of the key. HMAC is pretty resilient and changing the last part of the hash won't allow attacks on the a hash such as SHA-256.

Note that you only select 4 characters, of which the last one only encodes 4 bits (as it is at the end). That means you've got a check value the size of 2^22 encoded bits, i.e. a chance of 1 / 4194304 that you match a key that you didn't mean to match. If you generate a whole lot of keys you can certainly not use this to select one key from a set because of the birthday problem.

The security of HMAC is diminished with 22 bits as well, leaving you with 256 - 22 = 234 bits maximum security. Halve this for a usual setting of HMAC, so with a bit of handwaving, you're left with 117 bits.

Generally you take bytes from binary data *before* encoding to base 64. If you need base 64 you can separately encode the bytes afterwards.

---

Possible without significant reduction in quality: yes.

Advisable? Absolutely not, there doesn't seem any good reason to do this. Use a KBKDF (key based key derivation mechanism) instead to create a key fingerprint. You may use the HMAC using the normal key and an unlikely string for data for this.

Comment: That "normal hash" shouldn't necessarily be just the HMAC hash, since with a key longer than block size revealing parts of the hash is equivalent to revealing parts of the key. Probably better to use something like HMAC(k, 'fingerprint').

Comment: The question explicitly exposes part of the key already. The user is talking about using part of the key as KCV, before using it as input for HMAC, if I understood correctly. Yes, almost everything is more secure.

Comment: My point is that hash of the key *isn't* an improvement for keys longer than the block size.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand what you mean now, but I'm not sure if I understand the attack. Using a one way function such as a secure hash should not leak information about the message, even if it is a key. Yes, HMAC (or a KDF really) would be more secure, but I don't see how using a SHA-2 hash would significantly alter security (especially compared with leaking the key bits directly).

Comment: This wouldn't be used to identify a key from an unknown population of keys, but from a small set of keys on the order of tens of keys known to each party as legitimate keys.Maybe I'm

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, just to be clear, I meant the case where a key longer than block size if reduced to the hash of the key when used in HMAC. In that case revealing the full hash would allow arbitrary forgeries. If only a small part of either hash or key is revealed, I agree that there's no real attack.